# IF or CASE or WHILE LOOP. What's the Best approach?

Tags: t-sql

If it's greater than 10 set the variable to -1 and select that variable output.
If less than 10 select the variable as the output.

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 10 
SELECT @i = (@i * 10)
```

Thank You,

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you @marc you already edited the body of my post during my edit.

Comment: If it's greater than 10, do you want to ouptut that value, or -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot combine a select statement that assigns a value to a variable with an expression that returns data... So you need two statements...

```
Declare @I Integer = 4

Select @I = Case When @I > 10 Then -1 Else @I End
Select @I
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for.  Does this help?

```
declare @myResult int
select @myResult = case when @i > 10 then -1 else @i end 
print @myResult
```